# Spectrum analysis with Grafana (high resolution heatmaps)

Tags: data-visualization, heatmap, grafana

i read the heatmap [might crash on many bins](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/panels/heatmap/) and cannot find the feature to put out bitmaps/images of frequently changing data. It suffices if i could shift the image to the left and append another column of pixels on the right for the t+1 timestamp.

Sure most data reasoned about in aggregated fashion, but i try to get as close to the original 'picture' as possible. Does grafana have a pixel panel to quickly draw/update image data? example:
[image]
[image]

What other tools would you suggest? to visualize serverside generated data at the client in high resolution.